# Why svg text tag is ignoring the dy attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I am working on a `svg` image and I came up with a problem where the `dy` attribute of my `text` tag is ignored. Here is an example

```
<body>
    <svg width="100" height="100" style="border-style:solid;border-width:3px;border-color:grey;">
        <g transform="translate(20,20)scale(1)">
            <g class="node" transform="translate(0,0)">
                <rect height="27" width="56" rx="10" ry="10" style="fill: #ffffff;stroke:steelblue;stroke-width:2px"></rect>
                <text dx="6" dy="6">
                    <tspan x="0" dy="15">lxvirt129</tspan>
                </text>
            </g>
        </g>
    </svg>
</body>
```

Here is the fiddle for it [liveExample](http://jsfiddle.net/nikosdim/S4eaL/1/)

So my question is why when I change the value of the `dy` in the `<text>` tag the text doesn't change position? 
In my understanding the `dy` attribute indicates the difference in the **y axis** from the parent tag.

So why in this case is not working?

Thanks

Comment: So...how are you changing the `dy`?. I don't see any JS

Comment: @Paulie_D In my example I change the `dy` manually to keep things simple. In my code this is worked out from JS.

Answer (score 1):

Your markup is this...

```
<text dx="6" dy="16">
    <tspan x="0" dy="15">lxvirt129</tspan>
</text>
```

The dy attribute on the `<text>` applies to the first character but so does the dy attribute on the `<tspan>`. The `<tspan>` attribute wins as child attribute settings override the parents.

Comment: According to what you say the `dy` attribute of the `text` tag should be ignored but in my example is not. If you alter the `dy` the position of the text changes. But if you alter the `dy` it doesn't which confuses me. In my program I have multiple `tspan` tags in my text but I posted a simplified example in my question.

Comment: I think you need to rewrite your comment as it doesn't currently make sense.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Here is the corrected one: "According to what you say the `dx` attribute of the `text` tag should be ignored but in my example is not. If you alter the `dx` the position of the text changes. But if you alter the `dy` it doesn't which confuses me." Hope it is better now :)

Comment: Indeed, I had the wrong explanation. Corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **y="15"** in tspan tag, not dy="15". It will work then. :)

```
<body>
    <svg width="100" height="100" style="border-style:solid;border-width:3px;border-color:grey;">
        <g transform="translate(20,20)scale(1)">
            <g class="node" transform="translate(0,0)">
                <rect height="27" width="56" rx="10" ry="10" style="fill: #ffffff;stroke:steelblue;stroke-width:2px"></rect>
                <text dx="6" dy="6">
                    <tspan x="0" y="15">lxvirt129</tspan>
                </text>
            </g>
        </g>
    </svg>
</body>
```

Working JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6m3sX/